# Maven Multi-Module dependency

Tags: maven

i have a maven multi module project, with two modules: `moduleA` and `moduleB`, where `moduleB` is dependent on `moduleA`.

the project is pretty big and has been already long in use, often built, released, deployed, and so on, without any issue.

now i just wanted to check something in the dependency tree with:
`mvn dependency:tree` 
(on the parent)

and it comes out that maven fails complaining that the dependency of `moduleA` in `moduleB` can not be resolved.

The build order is Ok:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] moduleA
[INFO] moduleB
```

But it fails on `moduleB`:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] moduleA ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.861 s]
[INFO] moduleB ............................................ FAILURE [  1.477 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

and

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
org.test:moduleB:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.test:moduleA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.test:moduleA:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in 
https://artifactory.test.org/libs-snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are 
forced -> [Help 1]
```

i know i can fix it by building and installing `moduleA`, but why?

using maven 3.3.9

many thanks

Michael

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project, deleting the artifact in `.m2`, or running with `-U`?

Comment: @Charles: cleaning: yes. update: yes, to no avail.. if the artifact is installed, then it works... but i do not want that.

Comment: What about the other two suggestions?

Comment: @Charles: ?? i wrote an answer for every of your three ideas...

Comment: Maybe you have found a regression. Does `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree` work?

Comment: @RobertScholte: no. same problem. thanks